# Transforming to normal form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can 't transform the following differential equation system to normal form . Could you give me some clues?

$(D^2-D+5)x+2D^2y=e^t$

$-2x+(D^2+2)y=3t^2$

Where $D$ is differential operator

Comment: What is $D$ here?

Comment: $x''-x'+5x+2y''=e^t$

Comment: You should define what you mean by normal form? Do you mean a first order system of equations?

Comment: Yes Mryoumath.  It means first order system of equations

Comment: Did you try solving the second equation for $x$ and then using that to eliminate the $x'', x', x$ terms in the first? This gives a fourth order DEQ in $y$, which you can then write in normal form to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Let us proceed by substitution. From the second equation $-2x + y'' + 2y = 3t^2$, we deduce that
\begin{aligned}
x &= -\frac{3}{2}t^2 + \frac{1}{2}y'' + y \, ,\\
x' &= -3t + \frac{1}{2}y''' + y' \, ,\\
x'' &= -3 + \frac{1}{2}y^{(4)} + y'' \, .
\end{aligned}
Therefore, the first equation $x''-x'+5x+2y''=e^t$ rewrites as
$$
\frac{1}{2}y^{(4)} - \frac{1}{2}y''' + \frac{11}{2}y'' - y' + 5y = 3 - 3t + \frac{15}{2}t^2 + e^t \, .
$$
This nonhomogeneous linear ODE with constant coefficients can be written in the form of a nonhomogeneous first-order linear ODE system (see e.g. this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation)).